# go install command results in open /bin/palindrome: operation not permitted in mac

Tags: macos, go, macos-sierra

I have MacOS Sierra 10.12.6. I cannot install my go source file into the bin folder. I get '

```
go install _/Users/username/gowork/src/palindrome: open /bin/palindrome: operation not permitted
```

Please help me here.

Below are my go env variables
go env

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/username/GOWORK"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/08/1d18bh856db95kk0k65_sfnc0000gn/T/go-build043087036=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to do a    `sudo go install`

Comment: This resulted in sudo go install
go install: no install location for directory /Users/username/gowork/src/palindrome outside GOPATH
        For more details see: 'go help gopath'

Comment: There's no reason they should need `sudo`. `go install` should install to the user's Go working directory which should be user-writable.

Comment: @Adrian, in the normal case, yes. But he has actively set the GOBIN path to /bin so it seems OP wants to install system-wide.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install go using brew.

1. `brew install go`
2. `mkdir Go`
3. `cd Go && mkdir bin pkg src`

for Oh My Zsh terminal shell:

4. `vi ~/.zshrc`
   In order to edit this file, you’ll need to press “i” to enter “insert mode”.

5 Add this line

## Go

```
export GOPATH="$HOME/Go"
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Go to src folder and create your go app

That's it

Comment: You don't need `mkdir bin pkg src`, since the `go` tool will do that for you. Why `mkdir Go` when you could just use the default `$HOME/go`? Also, the env variables should be exported from a profile file rather than an rc file.

Comment: check my 3rd point I have created those 3 folders. and I am sure these settings work properly.

Answer (score 0):

`GOBIN` defaults go `GOPATH/bin`, bit you have it set to `/bin` which you don't have write access to.

Unset `GOBIN` and `go install` will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you landed here, I had the same issue. Here is how I solved mine.

I first checked my go path by running.

`go env | grep GOPATH`

This showed the GOPATH path. In my case it `/Users/titanium/go`

Then I set the GOBIN variable to "/Users/titanium/go/bin". By running

`export GOBIN="/Users/titanium/go/bin"`

After this, `go install` worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Finally ran from default $HOME/go

moved my source go file to GO/SRC/package folder and ran the go install command.

Thanks all